# Wordpress and product with more than 200 variation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I have a huge problem and i hope I can find a solution here.
In wordpress we have a product that has 3 type of variation 
HEIGHT: 15 yard
LENGTH: 50Y 25Y 15Y 10Y 5Y 1Y
With this variation wordpress work smoothly, but now we want to regroup the product (that now are a single product for Color) in one and add another variation for the colors. So we have a 36 different color and when I add all those variation in the final product page the time to load a single Color with the Color Swatch is like 10 second. Is this a limit for wordpress ? A better server could reduce the time to load ? Or we need to move to another platform like opencart or Magento  ? If there is something we can do with wordpress would be awesome. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

product variations in WooCommerce are treated as "child products" linked to the parent one.

Technically speaking, they are like different products and loading/querying a product with lots of variations usually slows down the website performances.

I doubt that a better server can significantly improve this, so if you wanna keep it on WordPress/WooCommerce the ideal solution would be to create 36 different products, one for each color.

200 variations should not be a problem on Magento, but if you go up with the number, queries can start "bottlenecking" and PHP memory can also be a problem.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now we have already one product for each color so we need to move out to another platform. Thanks again.